# MediaWiki get first letter of a string

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I want to make a function that will choose "a" or "an" depending on the noun. I am getting that noun from {{PAGENAME}}, which will have Opal, Emerald, Diamond etc.

Is there a parser function or something that I can use to get the first letter? Will also accept extensions or templates that do the same thing.

*(I know in English that a word starting with a vowel doesn't always use "an", but for my purposes this doesn't concern me much)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Template:A or an on English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:A_or_an). Note that it relies on other templates and modules that also need to be created on your wiki, which means you'll need [the Scribunto extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto).

Comment: In the StringFunctions are enabled as part of the ParserFunctions extension, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StringFunctions##sub: can also be used to make this template easier.

Comment: FO-nTTaX  - I think you meant to put this in a new answer, but this was useful for me and I made it work with that. Thanks!


AXO - Thank you! I was looking at that originally but couldn't get it to work, I was probably needing that extension you mentioned to make it work, and may go back and try to get that in the future, thank you for your response!

Comment: No I meant this as an addition to what AXO wrote, as on its own the sub function doesn't do it (as you pointed out in the question asked).